# Error 404 with dynamic routing in production using the new Router App in NextJS

Tags: next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm facing an issue with my Next.js project. It works perfectly in my local environment if dont use next preview, but when I deploy the app to production using Vercel or Railway or I use npx next build and npx serve@latest out, I encounter a 404 error when i try to enter in [dynamic] routes.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyAAy.png)
[Structure of the routing app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gz0HB.png)

For example the categoryId page.tsx is like this.

```
export default function CreateIndex({ params }: { params: { categoryId: string } }) {

  const [data, setData] = useState(papers);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filteredPapers = papers.filter((paper: Paper) => paper.category === params.categoryId);
    setData(filteredPapers);
  }, [params.categoryId]);
 

  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between p-2 md:p-24 font-mono">
      <div className="flex flex-col w-full max-w-5xl items-center justify-between text-sm lg:flex">
        <section className='grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 gap-4'>

          
            {data.map((paper: Paper, index:number) => {
              return (
                <PaperItem key={index} paper={paper}/>
              )
            })}
             

        </section>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}
```

I believe this is a problem with Next.js, but I can't find the documentation. The issue might stem from the URL structure.

Thanks I'm new in react and nextjs!

I have tried to add:

trailingSlash in the project

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
    images: {
      unoptimized: true
    },
    trailingSlash: true,
    // Optional: Add a trailing slash to all paths `/about` -> `/about/`
    // trailingSlash: true,
    // Optional: Change the output directory `out` -> `dist`
    // distDir: 'dist',
  }
   
  module.exports = nextConfig
```